# How to get Ubuntu to look like Windows XP?

Tags: 18.04, windows, 18.10, windows-xp, system-requirements

My Family has an old computer running Windows XP but it's so slow that I am going to put Linux on it, my problem is that I need it to look like Windows XP or it will be to hard of a change for my aunt. I am looking for a 32-bit os based on Ubuntu if possible. It also has to use vary little system resources and have low system requirements. Specs:

- 2 core Intle Pentium
- 2 gb ddr2 ram
- 256 gb 5400 rpm hard drive

Comment: I reckon this question is too broad to be answered within the limited scope of this Q&A site. You may want to try Ubuntu-based [Zorin OS](https://zorinos.com/). Its USP is that it lets you choose interfaces [resembling Windows](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/windows-xp-zorin-os/) or Mac OS X.

Comment: I've seen many many web sites that tell you how to dress up your Ubuntu to look like mac osx, win7, and winxp, so why not follow one of them. They all assume a certain starting point (which generally isn't a gnome base or 18.04/18.10).  Myself I'd start with Xubuntu or Lubuntu (I think easier on Xubuntu) - but I agree with pomsky - it's too broad a question.

Comment: Low- system resources is also very vague.  I was using a `dell latitude d610 (pentium m, 1gb, intel i915)` to test Lubuntu 19.04/Xubuntu 19.04 till they stopped producing x86 (32bit) ISO images - but do you class that low-system resources??  To me it is, but to get a useful answer you need to be specific.

Comment: Ubuntu is not a Windows clone. You can haywire it to *look* like WIndows, but it still won't *behave* the same way Windows does.  I have found that parents and grandparents are more open to useful, purposeful change than younglings might believe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Xubuntu more resource hungry than Windows XP?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422639/is-xubuntu-more-resource-hungry-than-windows-xp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/)? Uses LXDE GUI and based at Ubuntu distributive. Good solution for a weak computer. Same you can [install LXDE on your Ubuntu distributive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LXDE).

Comment: I agree with this. Lubuntu has a straightforward menu system and is an easy transition for XP users.